# Python 2.7 - Conditional passing empty k,v pairs to dict instead of moving to next iterator

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

EDIT 2:
posting more code that might make it easier to identify my mistake(s).  The code seems to ignore my "continue" statement, thus it processes words that should be ignored, which clutters my output with empty key/value pairs.

```
        for line in tweets_lines:
            total = line.split() ###this gives me each line broken out by word.  Need to get value of each word, then sum each line. 
            line_score = {}
            for word in total:
                if word not in scores: continue
                line_score[word] = scores[word] #Add words from Tweets that are found in AFINN sentiment file to new dictionary, then assign each the value from AFINN.

            line_sentiment = sum(line_score.itervalues())
            print (line_score, line_sentiment)
```

First post ever here, and I'm not a developer.  I am looping over a set of words, and I have a check to determine whether each word is found in a dictionary.  If the word is not found in the dictionary, I want to ignore the word and proceed to the next word. Words that are found in the dictionary get added to another dictionary.  My problem is that instead of skipping words that aren't found in the dictionary, my code is adding "empty" key/value pairs to the second dictionary. 
The words I'm looping over are in a variable called "total", so my code looks like:

```
    for word in total:
        if word not in scores : continue
        #do work
```

Where "scores" is the name of the dictionary I am checking against.

I have
also tried removing the 'not', and having an Else statement with the Continue command, but results are the same.  I realize I could clean this up outside of Python, but I'd like to do this the "right" way.  Can anyone provide guidance?

EDIT:  per suggestion, here's a screen shot from my console output:
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXTgV.jpg

the first line in the shot is what I want:  a dictionary with keys/values that were found in the scores dictionary.  The second two lines show output that I'd hoped would be discarded in the loop I reference above.
Note that I have tried it this way also:

```
    for word in total:
        if word in scores:
            #do work
```

but this gives me the same sort of output in the screen shot.  In short, I am getting the output I want - but I'm also getting "garbage" that I'd like my code to handle.  thanks again...

Comment: post an example along with expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are saying is:

For each tweet, if it contains special words generate a "line_score".  If it doesn't contain any of the special words, don't generate the score at all.

Sadly no "continue" will cover both situations no matter how you indent it.  These are separate things.  You must loop through the total words, then if they were no matches, don't generate the sum.

What you want is to detect if no scoring words were detected and not generate the sum if so.  You can set a flag if a word was detected, or you can optimize this by realizing that line_score will still be empty if nothing was scored.

```
tweets_lines = ['one two other', 'four other six', 'nothing matches']

scores = {
    'one': 1,
    'two': 2,
    'four': 4,
    'six': 6,
    }

for line in tweets_lines:
    total = line.split()
    line_score = {}
    for word in total:
        if word in scores:
            line_score[word] = scores[word]

    if line_score:  ## NEW: If line_score is empty, we skip this.
      line_sentiment = sum(line_score.itervalues())
      print (line_score, line_sentiment)
```

The output I got is:

```
({'two': 2, 'one': 1}, 3)
({'four': 4, 'six': 6}, 10)
```

Before adding the "if line_score" I got:

```
({'two': 2, 'one': 1}, 3)
({'four': 4, 'six': 6}, 10)
({}, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you!!  Marked this as Answer.  Two additional questions for my own understanding:  1. my code only has the line_score dictionary inside the for loop, but your code also lists it prior to that loop.  Is there a reason for that?   2.  given your "if line_score" addition (which makes all the difference), there really isn't a need to have the if/if not/continue at all right?  since you are saying that every word needs to be added to the line_score dictionary...

Comment: 1. True. That first `line_score = {}` isn't needed.  I'll edit. 2. no, not every word needs to be added... from what you said earlier, only scored words,

Comment: Got it.  So the key learning for me is that every word needs to be evaluated, they can't be filtered in the initial loop.  Only then can I apply the filter to get the results I'm looking for.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it make more sense to check for the words that are in the dictionary and do the work then? Like so:

```
for word in total:
    if word in scores:
        #do work
```

Doing so will already ignore the words not in the dictionary.

Comment: `if word not in scores: continue` has one advantage: it has one less level of indentation for `#do work` than not using it. Otherwise they are equivalent.

Comment: Indeed, what would be the best practice in this case? Or is it just a case of personal preference?

Comment: Personally, I'd lead with `if ...: continue` because if the whole body of the loop is controlled by the `if`, it's easier to grasp the whole "nothing happens in this case" in a line or two with the `continue`, where an `if` for the whole body needs you need to scroll to the end of the `if` to make sure nothing else happens.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
another_dict = {}
for word in total:
    if word in scores:
        if word not in another_dict:
            another_dict[word] = True
```

Alternatively, if you want to include more statements after the assignment, this formatting may be preferred:

```
another_dict = {}
for word in total:
    if word not in scores:
        continue
    if word in another_dict:
        continue
    another_dict[word] = True
```

Comment: Thanks Tom - the problem I'm having is that the "continue" statement doesn't seem to do what I want.  If "word" isn't in scores, I want to skip the word entirely.  But the code seems to process every word, not just the words in scores.  The result is I have a bunch of empty dictionary key/value pairs that clutter my output.

Comment: Sounds like an indenting problem.  make sure that you consistently use TABs or spaces but not both. A mixture can confuse Python and it may decide the "then" part of an if isn't what you expected it to be.  I tend to use spaces exclusively so that I don't get mixed up.